# Conditional Http Proxy Servlet

Tags: java, http, servlet-filters

Working on a http proxy servlet which is used to forward the request to another remote server.

NOTE: Cannot change the URL Pattern

Snippet of web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SomeServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pattern1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

SomeServlet.Java

Validates the requests to check for specific content in request body and if matches forward to remote server. (Working as expected)

but if the condition fails, request processing should continue as is.
what I have now,

```
public class proxyServlet extends HttpServlet {
/* it has all the init other configs*/

@Overrirde
protected void service(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        /* If true, returns which endpoint for remote server else returns null */
        String endPoint = checkForConditions(servletRequest);

        if(endPoint == null) {
            return; // this is not letting the app to continue with flow.
        } else {
           HttpRequest newR = new BasicHttpRequest(method, endPoint);
           doExecute(servletRequest, newR)
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot create a new request and forward since server will again catch the pattern and do it in a infinite loop.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE-Solved: As per the comment from @balusc, Used servlet-filter and on condition use a HTTPClient to send POST request to remote server else chain.doFilter(...)

Comment: Please explain "Which is not working..". Show your code and any error messages and the stack trace.

Comment: The answer is to use a servlet filter instead of a servlet. It's however very surprising that you basically answered this yourself by using the `[servlet-filters]` tag instead of the `[servlets]` tag on your question. The code which you have there is NOT a servlet filter. It's a plain servlet.